# Bubble sorting doesn't work to sort dynamic array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, dynamic

I have class City with following private data: name of city(type char), width(double),length(double) and height(double) of the city. I have to make dynamic array, which is inserted by constructor by default- City(),when the programs starts.Then the program uses method output() and prints inserted array of cities.mA is my object of cities.I should use bubble sort to sort the cities by their length.I have copy constructor, operator = and I have to convert double max(this is variable, used in bubble sort to store current max value) to type City and in this purpose I used contructor with one parameter: City(double max).The problem is that the sort doesn't work. I think that the problem is in my definition of constructor with one parameter(to convert type double to type city).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

class City{
private: char *name;
         double width;
         double length;
         double height;
public:

    void Output();
    City();
    ~City();
    City(double max){
        name = "";
        width = 0;
        length = max;
        height = 0;
    }
    double GetLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    double GetWidth(){ return width; }
    double GetHeight(){ return height; }
    char GetName(){ return *name; }
    City(const City& that)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(that.name) + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(that.name); i++)
            name[i] = that.name[i];
        //strcpy(name, that.name);
        width = that.width;
        length = that.length;
        height = that.height;
    }


    City& operator=(const City that)
    {
        name = that.name;
        width = that.width;
        length = that.length;
        height = that.height;
        return*this;
    }
};
City::City()
{
    char ime[20];
    cout << "Name= ";
    cin >> ime;
    name = new char[strlen(ime) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(ime); i++)
        name[i] = ime[i];

    cout << "Width= ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Length= ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Height= ";
    cin >> height;
}

void City::Output()
{
    cout << "Name is: " << name << endl;
    cout << " Width is: " << width << " deg" << endl;;
    cout << " Length is: " << length << " deg" << endl;
    cout << " Height is: " << height << " m" << endl;
    return;
}
City::~City()
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Destructor of City!" << endl;
    delete[] name;

}

int main()
{

    int n;
    City *mA;
    cout << "Input number of cities: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    mA = new City[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        mA[j].Output();
    }
    cout << "Cities from west to east, sorted by their length" << endl;


    double max = mA[0].GetLength();
    for (int j = 1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (mA[j - 1].GetLength()>mA[j].GetLength())
        {
            max = mA[j - 1].GetLength();

            mA[j - 1] = mA[j];
            mA[j] = max;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        mA[j].Output();
    }

    delete[]mA;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error description, what do you expe ct it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: A bubble sort has two nested loops.

Comment: You should use `std::swap` to swap values. Now your `mA[j] = max;` will create a new object from `max` each time (with the constructor you suspected). You can make that `explicit City(double max)` if you don't want the implicit conversion.

Comment: `name = "";` assigns a non constant pointer to constant data. Be really careful with that. For example, think on what will happen when this object is destroyed and `delete[] name;` is run. Consider setting `name = nullptr;` instead. You will receive much more useful error messages should you attempt to misuse `name`.

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
City::City()
{
    char ime[20];
    cout << "Name= ";
    cin >> ime;
    name = new char[strlen(ime) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(ime); i++)
        name[i] = ime[i];
    ...
}
```

First you have to fix the constructor. Although it is not necessarily wrong, you should not ask for input in the constructor. Add a separate function for `Input()` instead

```
City& operator=(const City that)
{
    name = that.name;
    ...
    return*this;
}
```

This assignment operator is wrong. `name` is a pointer, you don't want to assign the pointers (not in this scenario). You should be using the same method as before to copy the name instead:

```
name = new char[strlen(ime) + 1];
strcpy(name, ime);
```

bubble sort should be done like the method in below. Also, you have added `#included <string>`. You should be using `std::string` instead!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class City
{
private:
    char *name;
    double width;
    double length;
    double height;
public:
    City()
    {
        name = nullptr;
        width = 0;
        length = 0;
        height = 0;
    }

    City(const City& that)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(that.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, that.name);
        width = that.width;
        length = that.length;
        height = that.height;
    }

    City& operator=(const City that)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(that.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, that.name);
        width = that.width;
        length = that.length;
        height = that.height;
        return*this;
    }

    ~City()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }

    void Input()
    {
        char buffer[100];
        cout << "Name= ";
        cin >> buffer;
        name = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
        strcpy(name, buffer);
        cout << "Width= ";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "Length= ";
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Height= ";
        cin >> height;
    }

    void Output()
    {
        cout << "Name is: " << name << ", " << length << endl;
        cout << " Width is: " << width << " deg" << endl;
        cout << " Length is: " << length << " deg" << endl;
        cout << " Height is: " << height << " m" << endl << endl;
    }

    double GetLength() { return length; }
    double GetWidth() { return width; }
    double GetHeight() { return height; }
    char GetName() { return *name; }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    City *mA;
    cout << "Input number of cities: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    City *mA = new City[n];

    //read input
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        mA[j].Input();

    //bubble sort:
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(mA[i].GetLength() > mA[j].GetLength())
            {
                //swap values:
                City temp = mA[i];
                mA[i] = mA[j];
                mA[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        mA[j].Output();

    delete[]mA;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

manually sorting requires comparing of resorted entries
------- comment ---------
for (int j = 1; jmA[j].GetLength()) {
            ... exchange elements
            ... j-=2; //index of 
            ... if(j < 0) j=0; }
------- end comment ---------

if there will be used std::sort conditions are reliable checked by STL.
And there will only be checked compare conditions on callback function.

regards, Hubert Hermanutz